# AWS S3 uploading/downloading huge files with low memory footprint

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose we have an app that has very limited memory but has to upload/download huge files to AWS s3.

**Question 1 : what is the correct api to use when we need to upload/download directly to FS while having very limited memory? (like 200Mb)**

One of the options to upload object to s3 is [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File))

```
TransferManager.upload(String bucketName, String key, File file)
```

**Question 2 : will TransferManager.upload() put entire file into the memory or it is smart enough to stream content to s3 without filling up the memory?**

**Question 3 : do we have any api that can do [zero copy networking](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/)?**

**Question 4 : aws offers option to move files from s3 to slower storage if you define the policy, if the file is moved to low frequency access storage do we query it the same way? (my assumption is that s3 will block me for hours to get the file then my download will start) important thing is if this process is hidden for me as a client or i need to figure out where my file is now and use the specific api to get it?**

Pardon me for many questions, searched answers for while, found only bits and pieces but no explicit answers.

Comment: I understand that it makes sense to separate these to different questions, but for someone who is looking for this topic all the answers will be interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1, Q2: Dig for a multi-part S3 upload, that is what you are looking for.

Q3: Nope, S3 supports only standard and multi-part upload APIs for now.

Q4: No, it is working other way. For you, it will look like the file is stored normally and you will have access to it as soon as you uploaded it (several seconds), but the difference is in the price. It will be much more cheaper for you to store data, but more expensive to retrieve every MB.

Good luck

Comment: got lost regarding Q4, if file is moved to glacier its still accessible the same way as it is in s3?
When i query it and its in glacier, it will block for hours before actual download right?
I assume its cheaper with glacier, and expensive with s3 only... ?

Comment: No, you asked about slower S3 storage, not Glacier. Glacier, by fact is a standalone archive service, that was implemented to support S3 API. Glacier retrieval time could be several hours, but S3 itself supports different storage. If your app needs data less frequently, but requires rapid access when needed, then "Amazon S3 Standard - Infrequent Access" is your choice. You can find more here: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/

Comment: Here is even better explaination: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html