# How to handle large file uploads with low memory footprint?

Tags: go, amazon-s3, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm writing an application in Go where user can upload a file and it would be eventually uploaded to Amazon S3 bucket. I've written an endpoint using which user can upload a file as multipart form data. Once the file is uploaded, I'm uploading it to S3 bucket.

```
func UploadRoutes(route *gin.Engine) {
    route.POST("/upload", uploadHandler)
}

func uploadHandler(context *gin.Context) {
    fileHeader, err := context.FormFile("file")
    // check err

    file, err := fileHeader.Open()
    // check err

    // uploads to S3 bucket   
    err = utils.Upload(file, fileHeader.Filename)
}
```

But I am not sure where the uploaded file data is being store between two uploads. It seems like file would be in memory after upload from user is completed and before it is uploaded to S3 bucket (Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#File)

If that's the case, large file uploads would consume too much server memory. As a workaround, I can think of writing the file on disk and then initiating multipart upload to S3 bucket. Are there better alternatives?

Here is a related question but the I think I'm already using multipart upload as suggested in the answer: [AWS S3 uploading/downloading huge files with low memory footprint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37825846/5353128)

Comment: [ParseMultipartForm](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) spills temporary files after the specified memory limit is reached.  Use [MultipartReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartReader) to process the data as it's read from the request body.

Comment: @CeriseLimón But the process is sequential, I mean once the upload from user is completed then only I can start the upload to S3 right? So between these steps the data would be in memory. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Use [MultipartReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.MultipartReader) to process the request body as a stream.  MultipartReader does not buffer files in memory or on disk.

Comment: Does [Uploading file to Google Storage without saving it to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59053893/5728991) answer your question?  Replace use of the Google API with the corresponding S3 API.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Upload`, you can pass the multipart reader directly to s3 instead of storing files in server before uploading

```
func uploadHandler(context *gin.Context) {
    fileHeader, err := context.FormFile("file")
    // check err
    config := &aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-1"), // your region here 
    }
    AwsSession := session.Must(session.NewSession(config))
        uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(AwsSession)
        result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Bucket:      aws.String(bucketname),
        Key:         aws.String(filePath),
        Body:        fileHeader, // you can pass the reader here 
    })  
}
```